# Почему babel не транслирует мой ES6 код в ES5

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babel

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос такой установил `babel-loader` запускаю `webpack` смотрью в `bundle.js` в котором **абсолютно ничего не поменялось** то есть `let` как было так и осталось также и другие функции.Но при этом `webpack` сработал и никаких красных ошибок и начал отслеживания `watch:true`

Помогите пожалуйста  в чем может быть проблема?

вот мой **webpack.config.js**

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

module.exports = {
    entry: "./common",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename:"bundle"
    },
    watch:NODE_ENV == "development",

    devtool:NODE_ENV == "development" ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,

    module: {

        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: "babel",
            query:{
                presets:["es2015"],
            }
        }]

    }
};
```

**common.js**

```
let  welcome = require("./script");

welcome("script");
```

**script.js**

```
module.exports = function(message){
    alert(`welcome${message}`);
};
```

все файлы находятся в одном директории кроме **bundle.js** который находится в папке `dist`

Comment: И  на кой тебе `babel`?

Comment: не понял ? @Air

Comment: На  сколько я знаю уже все браузеры `ECMA-6` без проблем понимаю....

Comment: @Air уверен? https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: я говорил современные браузеры....

Comment: babel нужно когда надо писать что нибудь включая мертвые браузеры.Потому и завис над данной проблемой.

Comment: посмотри тут, очень доходчиво  и подолбно  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YfsAz-sNAo&list=PLqHlAwsJRxAOpWPtj2T6HhSzX-lKmKV2q

Comment: @Air спасибо как нибудь посмотрью :)

Comment: Там первые 2 видео установка самого `babel`, а далее `ECMA-6`-я

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы вебпак конвертил из `ES6` в `ES5` кроме `babel-loader` еще нужно установить `babel-preset-es2015`

```
module: {
  rules: [{
     test: /\.jsx$/,
     loader:'babel-loader',
     options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
  }]
},
```

UPD: и еще, чтобы вебпак конвертил `.js` файлы нужно в `test` указать это расширение

```
test: /\.js$/,
```

Comment: тоже самое ..не сработал ваш вариант.@torokhkun :(

Comment: @Избытоксусликов и еще, Вы же понимаете что вы натравливаете на реактовские расширения `.jsx` а в примере у Вас `.js` может Вам нужно `test: /\.js$/`

Comment: да сработало спасибо вам.Проблема заключалсья в том что у меня не было babel-core.А это я обнаружил тогда когда сменил реактовское расширения на js там подсказал консоль про error я установил и вуалья ваш ответ принят :) @torokhkun

Comment: А ответ то был на голосовании закрытия)))))....(+)